# can anyone help me to resolve the issue "An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: recaptchalib"

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha, captcha

I am updating recaptcha library to recaptchalib.

I am getting this error.

> An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: recaptchalib

1. Include the library recaptchalib.php in library folder.
2. User controller:

```php
    $this->load->library('recaptchalib');

    $data['fincaptcha_ok'] = $this->recaptchalib->recaptcha_get_html();

    $this->recaptchalib->recaptcha_check_answer($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field'),$this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field'));
    if(!$this->recaptchalib->getIsValid()) {
        $this->load->helper('directory');
        $data['error'] = 'incorrect captcha';
        $data['body_content']           = 'user/register';
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
```

3. View:`<?php  echo $fincaptcha_ok; ?>`

Comment: Can we see what does `$this->load->library' do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think you use [this](https://github.com/DannyNunez/codeigniter-admin/blob/master/third_party/recaptchalib.php) recaptcha lib.

this Library provides a set of functions and has no object implementation. That said it should work if you use it like:

```
$this->load->library('recaptchalib');

$data['fincaptcha_ok'] = recaptcha_get_html();

$objResponse = recaptcha_check_answer($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field'),$this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field'));

if(!$objResponse->is_valid) 
{
    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $data['error'] = 'incorrect captcha';
    $data['body_content']           = 'user/register';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

> As an additional information, eventually it's better to use the built in captcha helper. Take a closer look at their documenation [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html).